# Remove elements with HTML length less than X characters

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find all elements with `class=galleryLink` who's HTML is less than X characters and then remove them from the DOM. Here's my best guess:

```
if($('.galleryLink').html().length < 95){
    this.remove();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "who's HTML is less than X characters"? Do you mean the text contents?

Comment: Yes... I'm not talking about form fields, just DIVs with HTML content inside those DIVs. And it will primarily be IMG tags, so it will be actual HTML.

Comment: text contents is very different from html content. Do you mean to include all the special characters, encoding, leading whitespace, and comments? Or do you simply want to filter elements that have some text in them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking in the right direction, but you're not quite there. In your example, how would `this` ever refer to the elements you want to remove?

You'll have to apply that to all of the matching elements:

```
$(".galleryLink").filter(function () {
    return $(this).html().length < 95;
}).remove();
```

Note that the `.html()` method returns the markup within the element. You may prefer `.text()`.

The `.filter()` method applies a function to each element in the matched set. If it returns a truthy value, that element remains in the set. So after the filter, you'll be left with all the elements whose content is less than 95 characters in length.

The `.remove()` method applies to all elements in the matched set. Since the set has now been filtered down to the elements you want to get rid of, it should do the job.

Comment: What's the syntax for filtering out `:input` elements? `.remove(':not(:input)')` ?

Comment: @JeromyFrench - May as well do the work inside the `.filter` callback. `return !$(this).is(":input") && ...`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter down the elements before removing them:

```
$('.galleryLink').filter(function() {
    return $(this).html().length < 95;
}).remove();
```